# Using Nginx Proxy to Access Nifi and Nifi Registry over HTTPS with Docker

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, apache-nifi

I am trying to host Nifi And Nifi Registry in a VM and use Nginx Proxy to access them over HTTPS. At the moment I only need HTTPS to connect to Nifi (Not Nifi Registry). I have created a Docker Compose file as below:

```
version: '3'
services:
  proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy:0.9.3
    container_name: dev-nginx
    ports:
      - "443:443"
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - /etc/ssl/certs:/etc/nginx/certs/
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
  dev-nifi:
    container_name: dev-nifi
    image: apache/nifi:1.22.0
    volumes:
      - /etc/ssl/certs:/opt/certs/
    ports:
      - "8443:8443"
    environment:
      VIRTUAL_HOST: nifi.dev.com ###locally registered CNAME
      VIRTUAL_PORT: 8443
      # nifi.web.https.host
      NIFI_WEB_HTTPS_HOST: '0.0.0.0'
      # nifi.web.https.port
      NIFI_WEB_HTTPS_PORT: 8443
      # nifi.web.proxy.host
      NIFI_WEB_PROXY_HOST: 'https://nifi.dev.com:8443'
  dev-nifi-registry:
    container_name: dev-nifi-registry
    image: apache/nifi-registry:1.22.0
    ports:
      - "18080:18080"
    environment:
      VIRTUAL_HOST: nifi-registry.dev.com ###locally registered CNAME
      VIRTUAL_PORT: 18080
      # nifi.web.https.host
      NIFI_REGISTRY_WEB_HTTP_HOST: '0.0.0.0'
      # nifi.web.https.port
      NIFI_REGISTRY_WEB_HTTP_PORT: 18080
```

After running the `docker compose up -d` I am able to access Nifi Registry with this url "https://nifi-registry.dev.com/nifi-registry/". However, when I am trying to access Nifi, I https://nifi.dev.com/nifi the site is not loading at all. I have gotten the SSL certificates and mapped them in the volumes in Nginx Configuration. (I have also tried using just HTTP for Nifi and then it worked fine, but as soon as I changed the configuration to HTTPS, Nifi doesn't work). Any help would be appreciated! :)